# Android Studio Java - Which modifier should I use?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, access-modifiers

I'm kind of new to Android Studio and Java so bear with me please.

I'm making an app where you can keep scores with a dart game. I have a switch statement for which button is clicked. When the enter button is pressed, I want it to go to another Java file while using one argument, which is the input. Apparently I use both static and non static methods and that is wrong. How do I fix this?

Here is my first java file, witch is the from the screen file:

```
package com.example.jeroe.darts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.jeroe.darts.Score;


public class MatchScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_match_screen);

    DefineEventHandlers();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView InputTrue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextviewInput);
    TextView editTextScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextScore);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.TextViewInnerbull:
            editTextScore.append("50");
            break;
        case R.id.TextViewOuterBull:
            editTextScore.append("25");
            break;
        case R.id.TextViewClear:
            editTextScore.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.TextViewEnter:

            Score.enter(editTextScore.getText());
            // here i get an error:
            //non-static method 'enter(charsequence)' cannot be referenced from a static context

    }
}

public void DefineEventHandlers()
{
    // declare textviews Player 1
    TextView TextViewPL1Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewPL1Score);
    TextView PL1Dart1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL1Dart1);
    TextView PL1Dart2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL1Dart2);
    TextView PL1Dart3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL1Dart3);

    // declare textviews Player 2
    TextView TextViewPL2Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewPL2Score);
    TextView PL2Dart1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL2Dart1);
    TextView PL2Dart2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL2Dart2);
    TextView PL2Dart3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PL2Dart3);

    //T20, bulls
    TextView TextViewOuterBull = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewOuterBull);
    TextViewOuterBull.setOnClickListener(this);
    TextView TextViewInnerBull = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewInnerbull);
    TextViewInnerBull.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Enter, backspace
    TextView TextViewClear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewClear);
    TextViewClear.setOnClickListener(this);
    TextView TextViewEnter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewEnter);
    TextViewEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
}

} //end of the file
```

Then I need it to go to another file called score.java. Here I want it to keep the score and some other things:

```
package com.example.jeroe.darts;

public class Score {
int PL1Score = 501;
boolean player1 = true;

public void enter(CharSequence input) {

    int IntInput = InputConverter(input);

    if (player1 == true) //de input is = player 1
    {
        // do something
    }
}



public int InputConverter(CharSequence input) {
    int Input = Integer.parseInt(input.toString());
    return Input;
}

}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @Gavriel - found it, search for - `Score.enter(editTextScore.getText());`

Comment: I suggest creating separate `onClick()` methods for each button rather than one `onClick()` method with a huge `switch` statement. Of course, when you make several `onClick()` methods, they each must have different names.

Comment: Also, I suggest you do some research about creating object instances and `static` members. There is a lot of information about both of these on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//non-static method 'enter(charsequence)' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

It means you need an instance of Score:

```
Score score = new Score();
score.enter(editTextScore.getText());
```

Comment: You are my hero, it worked exactly the way I wanted to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "go to your second java file" you mean: You want to instantiate a new object based on your class Score.

If you have this object, as stated by [Gavriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661589/gavriel), you can call declared methods.

A static variable or method exists in the context of the class, and not in context of the object instance: For example you can define a static field that counts all the object instances created and every object you create can access this static field and access its content.

Member variables of a class can only be accessed in the context of a concrete object, static fields can be used by all objects. So it is not wrong to use both static and non static methods, but you should use them in the correct context.

Stated with a short example, it will become more clear.

```
public class Example {

   public static int instanceCounter = 0;

   private String memberVariable = null;

   public Example(String memberValue) {
      Example.instanceCounter++;
      this.memberVariable = memberValue;
   }

   public String getMemberVariable() {
      return this.memberVariable;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Example.instanceCounter);

      Example ex1 = new Example("value1");
      Example ex2 = new Example("value2");
      Example ex3 = new Example("value3");

      System.out.println(ex1.getMemberVariable());
      System.out.println(ex2.getMemberVariable());
      System.out.println(ex3.getMemberVariable());

      System.out.println(Example.instanceCounter);
   }

}
```

If executed the class produces the following output:

```
0
value1
value2
value3
3
```

As you can see the three objects do have three different member fields with the same name and every oject can have different values for the same field. But the static field instanceCounter exists only one time and can be accessed in the class context without having objects present at all.